# Android automated testing with Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, junit3

Does anyone have a good tutorial for setting up Jenkins to do unit testing for an Android project? I can do unit tests with Eclipse, but I need it for Jenkins.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/search?q=jenkins+android) seems like a good place to start. Maybe [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/dosearchsite.action?queryString=android) as well.